# (Done) This question should not have been closed as "opinion-based"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How to politely state moral objection](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183562/how-to-politely-state-moral-objection/183570)

This is no more "opinion-based" than any other question.

It's asking for advice regarding recruiters, interviewing, and potentially resumes.

I voted to re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

HOW exactly is his question "opinion based"? If it was important enough for him to seek guidance for from his peers on this site, then why shouldn't he be helped? It's an absolutely legit question and a good one, esp. for someone just entering the workforce.
It's a good "moral dilemma" question.
It should be re-opened. I've seen sketchier questions and I've been here just a few hours...